# How to use method of object in Android data binding?

Tags: android, android-databinding

Suppose I have this object:

```
public class Field
{
   List<String> list;
   public Field()
   {
     list = new ArrayList();
   }
   public boolean isOnTheList(String someText)
   {
     return list.contains(someText);
   }
}
```

Now I want to use this function on a xml with binding like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>

    <import type="android.view.View"/>

    <variable
        name="field"
        type="com.greendao.db.Field"/>        

    <variable
        name="user"
        type="com.package.User"/>
</data>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"    
    android:visibility="@{field.isOnTheList(user.name)?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE}"
    tools:context=".advisor.new_visit_report.activities.FieldsSelectionActivity"> ...
```

The problem is that is not working. Anyone has already tried this?

Comment: Are you really sure that `public class Field` is `com.greendao.db.Field`, instead of `com.package.Field`? Beyond that, please explain what "not working" means. Are you crashing? If so, what does LogCat show you?

Comment: Yes, that´s the correct Object. The app is not crashing, it's just that the visibility function is not working

Comment: are you setting name variable properly?

Comment: You could try to set the return value of `isOnTheList()` to `int` and return `View.VISIBLE` or `View.GONE` directly.

Comment: @RRR Yes, I'm setting them properly

Comment: @Amylinn I didn't understand what you said. Can you explain to me maybe with some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If everything else is set correctly, I would suggest to edit your method to return `View.VISIBLE` or `View.GONE` directly:

```
public int isOnTheList(String someText) {
    return list.contains(someText) ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE;
}
```

Used in xml:

```
android:visibility="@{field.isOnTheList(user.name)}
```

Comment: I'll try now and let you know!

Comment: I tried with something similar and it works! Thanks!